Why won't Ventoy boot from a flash drive
I recently bought a used Laptop, which had a German xUbuntu installation. I am vaguely familiar with xUbuntu.
Because it was in German I wasn't able to find my way around and decided to just plug in an empty hard drive. After doing so I got my 16 GB Verbatim flashdrive with Ventoy and Windows 10 installation on it.
I plugged it in and turned on the laptop. It just launched GRUB and I was stuck because I had no idea how to use it.
Any idea how to launch Ventoy from here, or remove GRUB altogether?


Enter your BIOS/UEFI via some key (laptops have typically F2 pre-defined).

Find the Boot order, name can differ, and every BIOS is different.

Here you should be able to set your USB drive as the first to boot from. (This process really varies from BIOS to BIOS).

I myself have tested Win10/11 install from Ventoy USB drive, and for some reason I had to disable Secure Boot. Just look around in your BIOS, it will be there somewhere.

It might be also possible to boot via One-time Boot Menu, typically F12.



All of the Information above is purely generic, as you did not specify your laptop model. If you edit your question to include that model, I might be able to help better. Will check in a couple of hours.
